# Hypothesis testing, power diagram

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Consider the statistical model $(\mathcal X,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$.

Let $ϕ$ be a statistic from $(\mathcal X^n, \mathcal A^n)$ to $([0,1],\mathcal B[0,1])$.

Consider the test $H_0$ versus $H_1$ with the decision rule: conditional on $X=x$ the decision will be to reject $H_0$ with probability $ϕ(x)$.

For example, if $x$ is observed and $ϕ(x)=1/2$ , we flip a coin to decide between the rejection or not of $H_0$.

In a Neyman Pearson test, we have that $ϕ(x)$ is either $1$, $0$ or $γ$ under some conditions on the likelihoods and a well defined $γ$

$E_0[\phi] = \int \phi(x) dP_0(x)$ is the error that occurs when $H_0$ is rejected even though it's true.

Furthermore we have $E_1[\phi] = \int \phi(x) dP_1(x)$.

The type 1 error is $E_0[\phi]$.

The type 2 error is $1-E_1[\phi]$.

The set

$\mathcal M = \{(E_0,E_1) | (E_0,E_1)=(E_0[\phi],E_1[\phi])$ for some $\phi \}$

is called the power diagram for $(P_0,P_1)$.

My teacher said that this power diagram looks like this:

[image]

where the "upper boundary" represents the Neyman Pearson tests.

He then listed some properties of the power diagram (which we can obviously see on his graph), but I dont understand how he found these ones:

$(1)$ $\mathcal M$ is symmetric with respect to $y= x$,

$(2)$ the "lower bound" of $\mathcal M$ is convex,

$(3)$ $\mathcal M$ is compact.

How can you find these from the definition of $\mathcal M$?

And I have another question: Why in a Neyman Pearson test $\phi$ of level $\alpha$ (meaning that $E_0[\phi]=\alpha$) do we necessarily have that $E_1[\phi]>\alpha$ for $P_0 \neq P_1$?

Concerning the diagram: I think that compactness and symmetry are obtained by considering $1-\phi$ and $\alpha \phi$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$, which are still statistics from $(\mathcal X^n, \mathcal A^n)$ to $([0,1],\mathcal B[0,1])$

It only remains to show the convexity of the lower boundary/concavity of the upper boundary

Comment: Could you define your symbols please? What are $\phi$, $E_0$ and $E_1$? You don't appear to have defined them

Comment: Please avoid [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471934/hypothesis-testing-power-diagram); choose where you want to ask.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I added some information

Comment: You seem to define $\phi$ as three different things; first you said it was a test, then you said it was a test statistic, and finally appear to define it as a function and said that it was a probability. Could you clarify what $\phi$ is?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Consider the statistical model $(\mathcal X, \mathcal A, P)$. 
$\phi$ is a statistic from $(\mathcal X^{n}, \mathcal A^{n})$ to $([0,1],\mathcal B[0,1])$.
I look at the test $H_0$ versus $H_1$ with the decision rule: conditional on $X=x$ the decision will be to reject $H_0$ with probability $\phi(x)$.
For example, if $x$ is observed and $\phi(x) = 1/2$ , we flip a coin to decide between the rejection or not of $H_0$.
In a Neyman Pearson test, we have that $\phi(x)$ is either $1$, $0$ or $\gamma$ under some conditions on the likelihoods and a well defined $\gamma$

Comment: Could you include it in the question?

Comment: The diagram ought to be symmetric around $y=x,$ not $y=x/2.$

Comment: @whuber You are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple null $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ against a simple alternative $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$, assuming that the supports of the underlying distributions under $H_0$ and $H_1$ are *not* disjoint.

Define the set $\mathcal M=\{(\alpha_0,\alpha_1): \phi\text{ is a test with }E_{\theta_0}\phi=E_0\phi=\alpha,E_{\theta_1}\phi=E_1\phi=1-\alpha_1\}$.

So $\phi$ is any test with probability of type I error $\alpha_0$ and probability of type II error $\alpha_1$.

Couple of straightforward observations:

- $\mathcal M$ is contained in the unit square, i.e. $\mathcal M\subseteq [0,1]\times [0,1]$.
- Suppose $(a,b)\in\mathcal M$. Then $1-\phi$ is a test with $E_0(1-\phi)=1-a$ and $E_1(1-\phi)=1-(1-b)=b$. This means $(1-a,1-b)\in \mathcal M$ whenever $(a,b)\in \mathcal M$.

Now take any two tests $\phi'$ and $\phi''$ with $E_0\phi'=a',E_1\phi'=1-b'$ and $E_0\phi''=a'',E_1\phi''=1-b''$.

Then for any $\lambda\in(0,1)$, the convex combination $\phi=\lambda \phi'+(1-\lambda)\phi''$ is also a test.

Clearly $E_0\phi=\lambda a'+(1-\lambda)a''$ and $E_1\phi=\lambda(1-b')+(1-\lambda)(1-b'')=1-(\lambda b'+(1-\lambda)b'')$.

Therefore, $\lambda(a',b')+(1-\lambda)(a'',b'')\in \mathcal M$ for any $\lambda\in(0,1)$ whenever $(a',b')$ and $(a'',b'')$ are members of $\mathcal M$. This shows $\mathcal M$ is a convex set.

For some more details regarding the properties of $\mathcal M$ you can check out Lehmann-Romano's *Testing Statistical Hypotheses* (pages 62-63) where the picture of the region is used in a corollary of NP lemma:

[image]
[image]